# Coordino permission issues?

Tags: permissions, php

I have downloaded the [Coordino](https://github.com/Datawalke/Coordino) and wanted to run it on Ubuntu, tried to run it but its giving the following errors

```
Warning: require(app/webroot/index.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/namal-geeks.com/index.php on line 55

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'app/webroot/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/var/www/namal-geeks.com:/var/www/namal-geeks.com/app/') in /var/www/namal-geeks.com/index.php on line 55
```

Tried to change the permission of the folders by using

```
sudo chmod -R 775 Coordino-directory        //using 775 as  Rinzwind mentioned it could be a security problem
```

but that didn't worked
seems it requires a file and cant get it because of permissions looked into the file and line where error is

```
line
 55    require APP_DIR . DS . WEBROOT_DIR . DS . 'index.php';
```

I am not sure how do I solve the problem ?

Help !

Comment: "sudo chmod -R 777 Coordino-directory" No you did not do a -R 777  ... you did a 775 because you understand the security risks using  777...

Comment: but still that doesnt solve the problem !

Comment: True. All my searches end up showing topics you created so I have no answer. I just do not want you to get into trouble trying to fix this by creating other problems. I am still looking though  ;)

Comment: Do you have a "app/webroot/index.php"? I find it suspicous it does not start with an absolute path. This leads me to believe it is a config problem related to the webroot and this file not starting in the webroot.

Comment: yes i do have that file its there exactly `app/weboot/index.php`

Comment: what is the absolute path of that file? `/var/www/Cordino-directory/app/weboot/index.php` or something else?

Comment: yes it is the path of that file

Comment: are these files writable as shown in the pic http://i.stack.imgur.com/4zK2l.png ?

Comment: Also, is a top level domain?

Comment: @Braiam how do i check that ?

Comment: https://github.com/Datawalke/Coordino/wiki/FAQ-and-Common-Issues#can-i-install-coordino-in-a-sub-folder-eg-examplecomcoordino-install-vs-examplecom

Comment: top level domain does that mean in the directory www ? if yes then i have it there 
and it said about uncommenting the line `Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));` i did it and the problem still persist.

Comment: I extracted the Coordino-master and pasted in the directory `/var/www/` and run it now it give this error `Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /Coordino-master/ on this server.
Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80`